# BGP source base routing question

Tags: cisco, routing, switch, bgp, isp

This question is little convoluted to explain but i will try my best, I have following scenario.

[image]

I have one ISP and i am getting 2x40G drops which you can see in diagram `Link-A` and `Link-B` (Both coming from same BGP AS) both Link-A & Link-B has associated subnet `Subnet-A` & `Subnet-B` both are `/23`, we run lots of public applicate so we need lots of public IP.

Question:

My ISP sending BGP `Default` route on both Link because we don't want to hold full BGP table. Now how do i tell my BGP `Subnet-A` take `Link-A` route and `Subnet-B` take `Link-B` route?  In short link source base routing? is there any other method we can use to achive this schenatio

- I am trying to avoid `PBR` because its kind of static route.
- Should i use load-sharing ?
- Can Local Preference solve this issue?
- Or this solution is not feasible?

Comment: Can you put subnet a and b in different vrfs?  If not can you put a and b on different switches?

Comment: VRF is little complicated because one of `Link-A` is live in production, we thought about VRF but seems too much work there.

Comment: Really you can think of both them in the default VRF right now so you could get away with just creating a new VRF just for Link/subnet B. Sometimes it takes more work to create a better network.

Comment: I need to buy switch to put them on separate switches, I have one more pair of Cisco 3064PX switches, does those switches can handle 40G traffic, if they can then i can terminate those link on them

Comment: Can't find a datasheet for a 3064PX, did find one for a 3064-X, [_Cisco Nexus 3064-X, 3064-T, and 3064-32T Switches Data Sheet_](https://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/products/collateral/switches/nexus-3000-series-switches/data_sheet_c78-651097.html), and that model does appear to have support for 40G.

Comment: I have `Nexus 3064-X`

Comment: If all networks are in the global table then I can't see any way to achieve this using normal BGP as you need to differentiate the routing based on source addressing and only PBR can do this.  PBR can be more dynamic if you tie it in with IP SLA.  You can have IP SLA monitor an IP address on the other end of each WAN link (or further on in the network) and it will only make the routes available if the IP is reachable.  That way, if the link is down it will follow the default route instead through the other link.

Comment: @KarlBillington do you know how do I tell my OSFP that ISP Link-B is down so now start sending traffic to c2 router?  Can you give me example how config will layout in PBR scenario?

Comment: you could add an additional IP SLA on C1 monitoring the IP of the other end of Link-B of C2.  You would need to make sure that the C2 Link-B subnet was in your internal OSPF.  Then add a second set ip next-hop verify-availability statement with the next-hop being router C2's next-hop address and tracking the additional SLA.  If the local Link-B is up, it will use that, if it is down and the remote Link-B is up, it will use that, alternatively, if both are down it will use the local Link-A or remote Link-A (default route)

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can make PBR more dynamic by tracking an IP SLA.

In this example, two IP SLAs are configured, one is to track the availability of 1.1.1.1 over Link-A and the other tracks 1.1.1.1 over Link-B

The PBR will send anything with source address in Subnet-A out to 3.3.3.3 (Link-A next-hop) as long as the SLA monitoring reachability through that link is up.  Anything sourced from Subnet-B will be sent out to 4.4.4.4 (Link-B next-hop) as long as the SLA monitoring reachability though that next-hop is up.

If either of the SLAs are not up, routing will fall back to the global table and follow the default route in this case.

```
ip sla 1
 icmp-echo 1.1.1.1 source-interface G0/1

ip sla 2
 icmp-echo 1.1.1.1 source-interface G0/2


ip sla schedule 1 life forever start-time now
ip sla schedule 2 life forever start-time now

track 1 ip sla 1 reachability
track 2 ip sla 2 reachability

ip access-list standard Subnet-A
 permit 192.168.1.0 0.0.0.255

ip access-list standard Subnet-B
 permit 192.168.2.0 0.0.0.255

route-map Choose-ISP permit 10
 match ip address Subnet-A
 set ip next-hop verify-availability 3.3.3.3 1 track 1

route-map Choose-ISP permit 20
 match ip address Subnet-B
 set ip next-hop verify-availability 4.4.4.4 1 track 2
```

Comment: Thanks, in above scenario what will happened if my `C1` switch dead or down, what will happen in that case?

Comment: You would need to configure the policy on both C1 and C2, if C1 was down it would follow the default OSPF route to C2 and then the same would be applied

Answer (score 0):

So I understand you have a / 23 and want a particular block to exit link A and certain block exit the correct link b?
You could advertise each / 24 in one of the links to ensure that link A / 24 always goes through that link, but this is not the best scenario because you would have a redundancy failure.
Another option would be to announce the two / 24 on both sides, and, put a prepent in the prefix that you wish to make worse on that link. Thus, you will not stop announcing both sides, and the worsening LINK A will not gain from the one that is unpredicted and you reverse the other link.
Now, if it is only the output of the machines in the subnet, you can perform a src nat so that subnet A clients leave the internet with the ip / 30 of your ISP of link A